# Can Glimpse provide details on ASP.Net 4.5 WebForms model binding?

Tags: webforms, model-binding, asp.net-4.5, glimpse

The MVC plugin for Glimpse can supply information on model binding that's taking place within a web application.

Do MVC and WebForms share the core libraries for model binding, and if so would installing the MVC plugin into a WebForms site:

1. Kill the application?
2. Do nothing useful?
3. Show lots of lovely debugging information?

Just trying to get an idea of how likely it is I'll spend the rest of the day unpicking an unholy configuration mess if I try something so crazy.

Comment: any final solution with latest version Glimpse.WebForms in VS 2013 - VS 2015 ? *ASP.NET 4.6.1 Web Forms legacy*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the model binding in WebForms and MVC are based on completely different implementations and aren't really related.

What this means is that installing the `Glimpse.Mvc*` package will basically do nothing useful.

You can/should install the `Glimpse.AspNet` package which will provide a good amount of lovely debugging information.

If you have anything specific you'd like Glimpse to support in WebForms, please submit a feature request on [our GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/glimpse/glimpse/issues).

Answer (score 1):

[Glimpse WebForms](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Glimpse.WebForms) 1.0.1 was released recently.  See the [Glimpse 1.7.0 released – First class WebForms support & MVC5](http://blog.getglimpse.com/2013/10/28/glimpse-1-7-0-released-first-class-webforms-support-and-mvc5/) blog entry on the [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) website for details about what is included.  Glimpse.WebForms provides page life cycle details, timeline integration, details about the ViewState and control tree, and more.